# Proving a function is NOT of exponential order

Tags: proof-verification, exponential-function, upper-lower-bounds

Prove that the function $e^{x^2}$ is not of exponential order. For contradiction, assume that 
$e^{x^2}$  is of exponential order. Then, by definition, $e^{x^2} \leq Me^{cx}$ for some $M,c$ .  But this implies that $M\geq 0$, since $e^{x^2}\geq 0$, so taking the logarithm will be defined. I have:
$e^{x^2-cx} \leq M$ 
But then by taking the natural logarithm I get:
$x^2-cx\leq logM$. This is essentially where I am stuck on reaching the contradiction. I feel I am done because it is obvious that a quadratic of this form is not bounded above by a fixed constant. However, I feel that this is not the best contradiction for this problem. Any advice starting from my last step would be appreciated. (Or if I made an error reaching my last step please tell me). Note, assume that we are working in the field of real numbers.

Comment: $$x-c>\log M\implies x^2-cx=x(x-c)>\log M$$

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt So you are saying that we can create a line $x-c$ greater than $logM$ and it follows that we can also create a polynomial with the same property?

Comment: I'm saying that for large enough $x$, then $x(x-c)>\log M$ for any $c,M$.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Ok, this is the conclusion i came to in my proof above. Do you think that it suffices? (It seems like an obvious enough contradiction. thanks. )

Comment: Yes, it suffices.